# Find element by xpath where xpath has variable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I would like to find the 'Code' from https://www.asx300list.com/ . The xpaths for 'Code' are as follows:

ABP

```
//*[@id="post-2"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]
```

AX1

```
//*[@id="post-2"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]
```

As you can see the xpath changes based on '[tr]'.

I have attempted to create a code which changes the variable for each xpath, but I keep getting an error saying it is not a valid xpath expression.

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Harrison Pollock\Downloads\Python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://www.asx300list.com/')
for tr in range(1,300):
    codes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="post 2"]/div/table/tbody/tr[{tr}]/td[1]')
    lencodes = len(codes)
    for i in range(lencodes):
        print(codes[i].text)  
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id="post-2"]/div/table/tbody/tr[{tr}]/td[1]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
Codes=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='tableizer-table sortable']//tbody//tr[*]//td[1]")))
 for code in Codes:
       print code.text
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: How did you come up with this xpath '//table[@class='tableizer-table sortable']/tbody//tr/td[1]'

Comment: I have manually checked your url and handled first column , If your issue is resolved then would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer

Comment: Yes, thankyou. Where did you that xpath from or how did you come up with it? Copy and paste?

Comment: @DipakBachhav : Could you explain what makes difference your answer so that OP accept your answer and deselect my answer?

Comment: @KunduK: I dont know why he deselect your answer first thing and I am not aware you have provided answer to his question.

Comment: @hpollock: You can use developer tool to form your xpath in your case tableizer-table sortable represent table and we are trying to form relative XPath. We dont need any header tags so we can skip that & then under tbody we have n no of rows , now youyou to handle codes from each row so instead of providing number we can use * with tr tag so till now your xpath should be //table[@class='tableizer-table sortable']//tbody//tr[*] after that you want 1st column so you can directly pass index of first column //td[1] :: final xpath //table[@class='tableizer-table sortable']//tbody//tr[*]//td[1]

Answer (score 0):

To Get the code from Table Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and following `xpath`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Harrison Pollock\Downloads\Python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://www.asx300list.com/')
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@class='tableizer-table sortable']/tbody//tr/td[1]")))
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

**Output**:

```
ABP
AX1
ABC
APT
AGL
AQG
ALQ
ALU
AWC
AMA
AYS
AMC
AMP
ANN
APE
APA
ADI
APX
ARB
ALG
ARF
ALL
AHY
ASX
ALX
AUB
AIA
AD8
AMI
AZJ
AST
ASB
ANZ
AAC
API
AVN
AVH
BBN
BOQ
BAP
BPT
BGA
BGL
BEN
BHP
BIN
BKL
BSL
BLD
BXB
BVS
BRG
BKW
BUB
BWP
BWX
CTX
CDD
CVN
CAR
CWP
CNI
CIP
COF
CGF
CIA
CHC
CLW
CQR
CQE
CNU
CIM
CWY
CUV
CCL
COH
CDA
COL
CKF
CBA
CPU
COE
CTD
CGC
CCP
CMW
CWN
CSL
CSR
DCN
DTL
DXS
DHG
DMP
DOW
ECX
ELD
EHL
EML
EHE
A2M
EVN
FAR
FBU
FLT
FMG
FNP
FPH
FXL
GDI
GEM
GMA
GMG
GNC
GOR
GOZ
GPT
GUD
GWA
GXY
HLS
HPI
HSN
HT1
HUB
HVN
IAG
IAP
IEL
IFL
IFM
IFN
IGL
IGO
ILU
IMD
IMF
INA
ING
INR
IPH
IPL
IRE
IRI
ISX
ITG
IVC
JBH
JHC
JHG
JHX
JIN
JMS
KAR
KGN
LIC
LLC
LNK
LOV
LYC
MAH
MFG
MGR
MGX
MIN
MLD
MMS
MND
MNY
MP1
MPL
MQG
MSB
MTS
MVF
MYR
MYS
MYX
NAB
NAN
NCK
NCM
NCZ
NEA
NEC
NGI
NHC
NHF
NIC
NSR
NST
NUF
NWH
NWL
NWS
NXT
OFX
OGC
OML
ORA
ORE
ORG
ORI
OSH
OZL
PDL
PDN
PET
PGH
PLS
PME
PMV
PNI
PNV
PPT
PRN
PRU
PTM
QAN
QBE
QUB
RDC
REA
REG
RFF
RHC
RIO
RMD
RMS
RRL
RSG
RWC
S32
SAR
SBM
SCG
SCP
SDA
SDF
SEK
SFR
SGF
SGM
SGP
SGR
SHL
SHV
SIG
SIQ
SKC
SKI
SLC
SLR
SM1
SOL
SPK
SPL
SSM
STO
SUL
SUN
SVW
SWM
SXL
SXY
SYD
SYR
TAH
TCL
TGR
TLS
TNE
TPM
TWE
UMG
URW
VCX
VEA
VOC
VRL
VRT
VUK
VVR
WAF
WBC
WEB
WES
WGX
WHC
WOR
WOW
WPL
WPP
WSA
WTC
XRO
Z1P

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: How did you come up with this xpath '//table[@class='tableizer-table sortable']/tbody//tr/td[1]'

Comment: If you see the code you are after it is inside table under 1st column.So you need to identify table first and then no of rows and then column 1 that is what the xpath.

Comment: @hpollock : whats the reason you haven't accepted my answer?Are not you are getting expected results?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a python problem with string concatenation. Try

`codes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="post 2"]/div/table/tbody/tr[' + str(tr) + ']/td[1]')`

Your final xpath still has `{tr}` in where the number should be, check this help for String concatenation: https://www.jquery-az.com/5-ways-python-string-concatenation-6-examples/

because your `tr` variable is an integer you also need to cast it to string `str(tr)`

BTW. I guess you could use a simpler xpath
`//*[@id="post 2"]//tr[' + str(tr) + ']/td[1]')`

Answer (score 0):

Omitting a tr specification [1] or [2] will give both, so you can use

```
//*[@id="post-2"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]
```